# Why ostream is not convertible to ostream?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I am doing some type checking in my project. The following example

```
using namespace std;

cout << ( is_convertible<ostream,ostream>::value ? "TRUE":"FALSE" ) << endl;
```

returns "FALSE".

Could someone explain why?

Comment: You can't *convert* something to what it already is.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If I use `int` to `int` it returns TRUE

Comment: Then it probably have something to do with streams not being copyable.

Comment: What you should be asking is `is_convertible<ostream&, ostream&>` :-) "Can I use this lvalue as that lvalue?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`is_convertible` tests if an imaginary function

```
 To test() { return std::declval<From>(); }
```

is well formed ([source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible)).

`std::ostream` is an alias for a `std::basic_ostream<char>`.  Its copy constructor is deleted, and its move constructor is protected.

So the `test` imaginary function is not well formed.

In short, you asked if you can move construct an ostream from an ostream, and the answer is "no".

Comment: Interesting, does that mean guaranteed copy/move elision changes the expected result?

Comment: @chris No, no change -- `decltype(declval<From>())` is `From&&`, which doesn't trigger guaranteed elision.  If `declval<From>()` was `From` it would.  ([source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval))

Answer (score 3):

You can't copy an `ostream` (it would make no sense in terms of internal `FILE*` representation). So you want to test with references instead (which is always a little safer than pointers):

```
std::cout << std::is_convertible<std::ostream&,std::ostream&>::value;
```

Answer (score 2):

The copy constructor of [`std::ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/basic_ostream) is explicitly deleted. The test [`std::is_convertible<From, To>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) tells you if an implicit conversion is possible, but it isn't for ostreams. Most likely you want to use [`std::is_convertible<T*, ostream*>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of).